# Displaying results from a mySQL database ...how to add a table after X results?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a script that gets results from a mySQL database and then outputs them, 4 on each row, 20 total. Sort of like:

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
```

What I'm trying to do, is have the script output a piece of code (that I'll then HTMLify) after the first 4 rows. How would I do that? So that the result would be:

```
X X X X
something else
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
```

Here is my current code:
(Note I on purpose deleted the mySQL query and that stuff, to make it easier).

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<? 
$columns = 4;
$results = 20;
for($i = 0; $i < $results; $i++)
{           
if($i % $columns == 0) { ?>
<tr height="15" valign="top">
<? } ?>
<td width="20%">OUTPUT GOES HERE</td>
<? if(($i % $columns) == ($columns - 1) || ($i + 1) == $results) { ?>
</tr>
<? } ?>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Your ascii art doesn't match your description. It says something else after only one row.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, because it's supposed to display something else ...some other kind of content, after the first 4 results, then continue with the results :) Basically a colspan 4 table with "something else" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($i == 4) { /* Or 5 if you only want to show it when $results > 4 */
  echo '<tr><td colspan="4">something else</td></tr>';
}
```

Or am I missing something crucial?

I think your code is really hard to read and maintain, by the way. I would start by building a two-dimensional array of what I want and then output that.

Comment: That should be a 4, shouldn't it?

Comment: Walkerneo, you are correct. But it depends on if you want to show "something else" when it's only four results. Where to put it (at start or end of the loop) depends on this as well.

Comment: With a 4 it works perfectly. Wish I could credit you both, so thank you very much :)